# iOS Game Center simple leaderboard

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, game-center

I have an iOS app using Sprite Kit that I would like to add a simple leaderboard.  I have tried several tutorials, but all are for an older version of Xcode and iTunes connect.  As of now I have successfully authenticated the user (ie. when I open the app it says welcome back, or asks to log in if I am not logged in).

Could someone please point me in the direction of a tutorial that encompasses a simple leaderboard (such as in Flappy Bird) that will explain the iTunesConnect side and coding within my app that is up to date with iOS 7 and Xcode 5?  Thank you!

Comment: It's will help you! I used this tutorial, it's very easy!<br>
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-game-kit-framework/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apple documentation for leaderboards is quite good. It explains how to do the iTunes connection portion and another page has the Xcode implementation with code examples.
You can find the iTunes connect info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/Leaderboards/Leaderboards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013726-CH2-SW1
The code examples are here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH7-SW3
Outside of that the app coda link that Iraklii mentioned is a great one.

Comment: second link is dead

Comment: @Thunk fixed the link.